# How to expand a div having a content when a user logs-in , no click function just by using $(document).ready function

Tags: javascript, jquery

Need to expand a `div` without any `click` function , its should be expanded automatically when document loads. Used `jQuery` `animate` method but i'm unable to do it

```
$(function(){
    $("#wish_card").animate({
         height: "200px"
    });
 });
```

Comment: are you binding any data on page load ? you can also use window.load function

Comment: YEs i'm binding data ,but the real thing is that the div should expand after the page loads

Comment: In asp.net ? then use scriptmangar.RegisterStartScript after the data binding

Comment: nope, its javascript

Comment: $(window).load(function(){ }): this will work.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `$(document).ready()` method provided by `jQuery`. This will fire up the `animate` method whenever the page is loaded.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#wish_card").animate({
         height: "200px"
    });
 });
```

Demo: [JsBin](https://jsbin.com/revujazena/edit?html,css,js,output)

Answer (score 0):

```
   $(window).load(function() {
      $("#wish_card").animate({ height: "200px" });
   });
```

Comment: Although this may answer the question, please provide any explanation you can to make sure people understand what is happening here.

Comment: thanks a lot for the suggestion I will keep it in mind while answering

Answer (score 0):

May be this will be very usefull to you

we are commonly use

```js
  $("document").ready(function() {
    // The DOM is ready!
    // The rest of the code goes here
  });
```

And the shorter version is

```js
  $(function() {
    // The DOM is ready!
    // The rest of the code goes here
  });
```

and this is the final best practice

```js
  (function($, window, document) {

    // The $ is now locally scoped 

   // Listen for the jQuery ready event on the document
   $(function() {

     // The DOM is ready!

   });

   // The rest of the code goes here!

  }(window.jQuery, window, document));
  // The global jQuery object is passed as a parameter
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This out:

```
$(function(){$("#wish_card").animate({ height: "200px" })();
```

For your reference:

[Edited demo Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/c9k6uzt4/7/)